# How to make sure a file handle has been closed before next operation?

Tags: php, while-loop, filehandle

This is the code I have so far, I wonder if it's correct?

```
$handle = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$closed = fclose($handle);
while($closed){
    DOAWESOMETHINGS(); // btw I only want to have this run once for each handle
    $closed = false;
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? After calling `fclose` the handle is hopefully closed, and if it isn't there is nothing you can do about it. What do you need the `while` for?

Comment: I need to rename the file and sometimes the file handle hasn't been closed yet. So the next operation requires the handle to be closed. This is usually a windows issue. Thank you.

Comment: So actually instead of `while` I would prefer a do_this_right_after file has been closed operator.

Comment: Dont know any details, but as far as I know `fclose()` should block, until the handler is really closed.

Comment: According to this comment (and a few others on the same page) http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php#102274 there seems to be a slight delay (somehow??) in those sequential actions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check whether the handle has been closed or not using this statement

```
if(!is_resource($handle)){
   //Handle closed
}else{
   //Handle still open
}
```

Therefore, if you need to ensure that fclose has worked before running the next function, you can use this loop:

```
while(is_resource($handle)){
   //Handle still open
   fclose($handle);
}
do_awesome_things();
```

Note: You should also use `break;` to end while loops when you need to. In this instance the loop will not end until the handle is closed.

Comment: but I wonder if this will will wait for the handle to be evaluated or will it fire right when it reaches the code line. You see there seems to be a delay between the file handle being closed order and the actual file being closed so the instantaneous firing of codes fails to operate sometimes when the handle is still being closed on window's end. Thank you.

Comment: One small source of confusion is that a closed resource still appears to be a resource if you `var_dump` it (appears as `resource(n) of type (Unknown)`), but `is_resource` does return false on it. You might want to set the handle to null after closing to avoid confusion.