# PHP: Why file can only be written the first time and subsequent writes fail?

Tags: php, file-io

**My code:**

```
function log_message($user = "", $message = "") {
    $log_file = LOG_PATH;
    // if we can open the file
    if($handle = fopen($log_file, "a")) {
        $timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d:%H %H:%M:%S", time());
        $content = $timestamp . " | [{$user}] | " . $message . "\n";
        fwrite($handle, $content);
        fclose($handle);
    } else {
         die("error opening log file: {$log_file}");    
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
The first time I can write to the file no problem but any subsequent writes don't get make it through and falls into the else statement?

**Other info:**
The site is hosted on godaddy and i have set the privacy permissions on the folder to be writable.

**What I tried:**
I used the function

```
file_put_contents($log_file, $content . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

but same result.

I also tried the solution mentioned in this question: [How to make sure a file handle has been closed before next operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650361/how-to-make-sure-a-file-handle-has-been-closed-before-next-operation)